# Gem installation error during MYSQL gem installation in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I tried to install ruby gems in my windows 8 but i shows some error after someone told to use another way as given below

subst X: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin" 
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=X: --with-mysql-lib=X:\lib\opt 
subst X: /D

i tried using this ways everthing works but one error that is

mysql.h is missing

now what to do with this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install mysql before installing mysql gem. Follow this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-installation.html) on how to install mysql on windows

Comment: can you give any link for the same installation in Ubuntu ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql

Comment: Ohh!! so it then install the latest version?

Comment: Its actually sudo apt-get install mysql-server. Ubuntu repository has version 5.5. If you want more latest version, you will have to download the package manually.

Comment: mysql cant install in port 3306 when i tried to reinstalling my mysql